# Importing custom attributes in Magento via Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to import a custom attribute via the Magmi plugin. It works fine for most of the properties, but for one custom property I've added to the default attribute_set. These are the settings for this custom attribute:
[image]

And this is an example of the CSV.

```
sku,attribute_set,name,description,price,product_id,categories,image,small_image,thumbnail,type,weight,store                                                                            

SomeSKU,default,"Some name",”Some description”,13.37,1111111,Group/subgroup,Big_image.jpg,small_image.jpg,thumbnail.jpg,simple,10,admin
```

It imported fine but I don't get the Product ID in the field at all. Nor the description or image... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the raw CSV, make sure you are wrapping the `product_id` column values with double quotes.

```
"11111111"
```

Magento stores the values of the text fields as strings, and if Magmi sees an integer with no quotes it may not import it for your attribute.

Also make sure your `product_id` is added to the **attribute set** you're importing on (default).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't get back to you sooner because I tried it out and fiddled around with it. But that doesn't seem to be the case. I m getting this error however: SKU 10063 - 1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pc4gamers`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE ) -